# vue - How a normal link could act like <route-link>?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have two pages routed:

`Home > Results`

Inside 'Home', I have a button/link which is not in `<route-view/>` and I want this button to redirect to `Results.vue` passing a parameter.

This parameter named `activeTab`, has to open the desired `vue-tabs`, which I can't accomplish, because it's getting nothing from variable:

code:

**`Home.vue`**

> ```
> <div class="row">
>      <Notes refName="Relationship" />
>      <Notes refName="Support" />
> </div>
>
> ...
>
> <script>
> import Notes from '@/components/Monthlynotes.vue'
>
> export default {
>      name: 'home',
>      components: {
>           Notes 
>      },
> </script>
> ```

**`/components/Monthlynotes.vue`**

> ```
> <b-card>
>      <p class="card-text">{{ refName }}</p>
>      <b-link class="right" :activeTab="refName" href="/results">More</b-link>
> </b-card>
>
> ...
>
> <script>
> export default {
>   props: {
>       refName: String,
>   },          
> </script>
> ```

**`Results.vue`**

> ```
>  <vue-tabs type="pills" v-model="tabName">
>    <v-tab title="Relationship">
>      <RelDT msg="Results view"/>
>    </v-tab>
>    <v-tab title="Support">
>      <SupDT msg="Results view"/>
>    </v-tab>
>  </vue-tabs>
>
> ...
>
> <script>
> import RelDT from '@/components/DataTable.rel.vue'
> import SupDT from '@/components/DataTable.sup.vue'
>
> export default {
>   name: 'results',
>   props: {
>     activeTab: String
>   },
>   components:
>     {
>       RelDT,
>       SupDT,
>     },
>   data() {
>     return {
>       tabName: activeTab
>     }
>   }
> }
> </script>
> ```

**`App`**

> ```
> <router-link :to="{name:'results', param:{activeTab}}">Results</router-link>
> ```

How can I make this `<b-link>` route if it was a `<route-link />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the `b-link` component supports the `:to` property. To be found [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/router-links/)
The value of the property will be passed to `router.push()`.

```
<b-link :to="{name:'results', param:{activeTab}}">Redirect me</b-link>
```